# Use attr_was and attr_changed? in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Transaction` and `Account` models in money management application with the following associations:

```
Transaction belongs_to :account
Account has_many :transactions
```

When user create transaction and add it to account, Rails runs method `add_to_account` in `Transaction` model to add amount of transaction to `balance` field in account.

I update the transactions page through AJAX and in `create.js.erb` I have the following line...

```
$('#account_<%= @transaction.account.id %>').replaceWith('<%= j render @account %>');
```

...to update account's form on the page.

When user updates transaction and change it's account, Rails runs `add_to_account` for two accounts: `account` and `account_was`.

I want to update both account's forms on transactions page, so I have the same line in `update.js.erb` to update `account`, but I don't know how to update `account_was` on the page, cause I get an error

```
undefined method `account_was' for #<Transaction:0x000001094e93f0>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Dirty attributes are meant to be used on properties, not on objects.

So it's not a view issue, you have to implement your own diff tool.

Comment: Are there any common practice, how to do it?

Comment: not really, how do you set the account? not sure if it should be a method in model or controller